# jQuery select object using their children condition

Tags: jquery

I have sample html code:

```
<div class="category">
     <div class="product">
         <!-- some product info -->
         <input type="text" value="0" /> <!-- it is quantity -->
     </div>
<!-- ... other products -->
</div>
<!-- ... other categories -->
```

So I need to get all categories using jQuery, where at least one product has positive quantity.

Something looks like this (in C#)

```
var filteredCategories = categories.Where(c => c.Products.Any(p => p.Quantity !=0));
```

how to do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.product', '.category').filter(function() {
    return parseint($(this).children('input[type="text"]').val(),10) !== 0;
}).dosomething();
```

You should consider adding a class to the quantity input to target it, as any other text inputs inside the `.product` element would also be selected with this method.

Comment: @Tomalak - First one means "above zero", the other is "not zero", they should both work, but I used the latter as I was unsure what this was used for. Some e-commerce system will allow negative numbers in quantity when removing items from a cart etc. and since the question was specifically "not zero", I used that, but I see now that it says "positive value" in the question, so both would work just fine, and since zero equates fo "false" you don't have to use an operator at all really.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `.filter()` jQuery method

```
var filtered = $(".product").filter(function(){return this.find('input').val()>0});
```

or simply

```
var filtered = $('.product:has(input[value!=0])');
```

jQuery documentation for [:has Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: Your second solution is definitely the most elegant, I like it.  Here's a link to :has syntax for selectors: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following

```
$('.product').​​​​​​​has(':text[value!=0]')
```

this will give you all `.products` that have a textbox with a value <>0

have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cjDt2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.product input[value!="0"]').closest('.product');
```

Maybe something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
$("div.product input[value!=0]:text").parents(".category")
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bavkN/1/)**